# Python3 Determine if a Program is Running on GCP?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, architecture, cloud

Is there a Python3 library which will determine if we are running on GCP or another cloud architecture as opposed to a native architecture?

Something like platform.platform() or jaraco.docker.is_docker(), but for the cloud?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. Each cloud vendor provides unique interfaces and usually environment variables, system services, etc that can be used to detect the cloud vendor. For Google, I use a simple method of connecting to the Metadata server for compute services.

For Python look at libraries such as `cloud-detect`. This is not a recommendation, just a link.

[cloud-detect](https://pypi.org/project/cloud-detect/)